# gradle cannot compile, but final Annotation var is not syntax error

Tags: java, gradle

Using gradle 4.10.2

```
@Table
public class MyClass{
    public static final String COL_NAME = "name";
    public static final String COLTYPE_NAME = DB.DataType.VARCHAR;
    @Column(name = COL_NAME, columnDefinition = COLTYPE_NAME)
    private String name;
}
```

This should not be a syntax error, but when I run `gradle clean publishtomavenlocal`, I get

> @Column(name = COL_NAME, columnDefinition = COLTYPE_NAME) error: element value must be a constant expression
>
> > ```
> >                                              ^
> > ```

the above is pointing at `COLTYPE_NAME`.

DB.DataType.VARCHAR is defined as

```
public final class DB{
    public static final class DataType{
        public static final VARCHAR = "varchar";
    }
}
```

How to fix this problem with gradle?

Comment: It is not a Gradle problem, it's a Java problem, caused by the fact that `DB.DataType.VARCHAR` is not a **compile-time** constant. `COL_NAME` is a compile-time constant, since it is declared in the same compilation unit (source file), but `DB.DataType.VARCHAR` references a different compilation unit that can be compile separately, so it is not a compile-time constant to *this* compilation unit.

Comment: This is so weird. I have been doing this for quite a while and didnt have problems before.